# Variable access in method of class

Tags: php, variables

I have listed code:

```
class myClass {

public $url;
public $content;
public $ip;

public function analysis()
{       
    $list = array('http://site.ru?url=http://'.urlencode($this->url) => 'get_tcy');

    function request_callback($response, $info, $request)
    {
        //at this place I need print content of $list variable
    }

    $rc = new RollingCurl("request_callback");
    foreach ($list as $key => $value) 
    {
        $request = new RollingCurlRequest($key);
        $rc->add($request);
    }
    $rc->execute();
}
```

But I have problem with printing content of variable.
How can I print it in needed place?

Comment: And you can't pass it to `request_callback()` as a parameter?

Comment: Why can't you do that?

Comment: Its a specific of Class and using callback function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```
$fn = function ($response, $info, $request) use ($list) {
    var_dump($list);
};
$rc = new RollingCurl($fn);
```

More info [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320521/use-keyword-in-functions-php).

Comment: Those codes are syntax's incorrect. Use of correct form impossible. I need other solution.