# Access external variable from a function

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to count the number of positive values in an input string. So, I am

- Converting the string to Array
- Iterate through the array and check if the num is positive

This works fine when I use a foreach loop.

But, I am trying to get this to work using the standard [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

```
$handle = fopen("php://stdin","r");
$positiveCount = -1;

fscanf($handle, "%d", $nums);

$arrayString = fgets($handle);
$array = explode(" ", $arrayString);

array_walk($array, function($num, &$positiveCount){
    if($num>0){
        print("In positive : {$positiveCount}\n");
        $positiveCount++;
    }
});

print("Total Count : {$positiveCount}");
```

I expected **$positiveCount** to be passed as reference to the function and incremented withing in.

This is my output,

```
$ php plusMinusNotWorking.php 
4
1 2 0 -1
In positive : 0
In positive : 1
Total Count : -1
```

Pass by reference seems not be working here. Is it because I am using an anonymous function? My expected output is

```
$ php plusMinusNotWorking.php 
4
1 2 0 -1
In positive : 1
In positive : 2
Total Count : 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are not passing

```
$positiveCount = -1;
```

to your array_walk() function.

i think you need to do

```
array_walk($array, function($num) use (&$positiveCount) {
    //your code
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: Thanks!. I have seen this usage, but was trying to figure out the documentation for it. This question also gives more info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320521/use-keyword-in-functions-php

Comment: You are welcome ), and yes that is a very helpful post.